# How to escape parent div click in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I use Angular8 and have a `div` which has a routelink,
within the `div` I have a checkbox besides other things, like below

```
<div [routerLink]="['/somewhere', blablabla]">
<!--some other components if you click it goes to the routelink-->
  ...
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myModel" value="{{someValue}}" 
        (change)="myFunction()"></mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

The problem is when you click the checkbox itself,
it takes you away by the parent div's routelink, skipping my (change) function

I don't want that, I want to have the checkbox change function called,
because I need to do something different there, not going away with the routelink.

Btw, I do need to call (change) NOT (click), how should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `$event` object to change handler i.e.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myModel" value="{{someValue}}" 
                            (change)="myFunction($event)"></mat-checkbox>
```

then invoke [`.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) method from the event handler

Comment: this is not working, if I use (click)="myFunction($event)" and event.stopPropagation() or event.preventDefault() , it is working, but not for (change),  it is not working,  I put console.log to to confirm it even not calling my change function

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Satpal's suggestion I realize that the click is ahead of change so there I can stop the event from propagation, and just keep the (change) function as it is, like below,
It is working as I want, click the checkbox it does not go away.

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="myModel" value="{{someValue}}" 
                (click)="hereJustStopThePropagation($event)"
                        (change)="myFunction()"></mat-checkbox>
```